# How to debug why a HTTP fetch in file_get_contents() is not working

Tags: php

I am trying to use `file_get_contents` in different way. Somehow it's not working by this way. Please see the code

```
<?php
$attrb = "https://html5andcss3.org";
$htmlcontent = file_get_contents("'" .$attrb . "'");
echo $htmlcontent;
?>
```

I got the error message

[image]

But when I use this code in normal way, it works fine. Please see the working code below

```
<?php
$htmlcontent = file_get_contents('https://html5andcss3.org');
echo $htmlcontent;
?>
```

My problem is that, I will get the URL in a variable and I need to start from there. So I can not directly put the URL.

Comment: `"'" .$attrb . "'"` is `"'https://html5andcss3.org'"` . There's way too many quotes.

Comment: why are you wrapping the var in quotes? Just.. use the var?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable's value is **already** a string. You don't need to surround it with extra quotes:

```
$htmlcontent = file_get_contents($attrb);
```